# Entity Framework in SaveChanges() a child PK is set to 0 while the parent FK is still good

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I have a situation with an Address model that is a property in several other models. Including the case of the State model has both an Address & County child property and County also has an Address property.

I address this in part with:

```
public class StateConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<State>
{
    /// <inheritdoc />
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<State> builder)
    {
        builder.HasOne(x => x.Address)
            .WithOne()
            .HasForeignKey<State>(x => x.AddressId)
            .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.ClientSetNull);
    }
}
```

And in part with overriding `SaveChanges()` and `SaveChangesAsync()` with the following:

```
var deletedCounties = ChangeTracker.Entries<County>()
    .Where(e => e.State == EntityState.Deleted)
    .Select(e => e.Entity).ToList<County>();

foreach (var countyOn in deletedCounties)
{
    // remove the child events for the county
    var county = await Counties
        .Include(c => c.Events)
        .Include(c => c.Address)
        .Where<County>(c => c.Id == countyOn.Id)
        .FirstOrDefaultAsync();
    if (county == null) 
        continue;
    Events.RemoveRange(county.Events);
    Addresses.Remove(county.Address);
}
```

The above fails! `Addresses.Remove(county.Address);` fails because `county.Address.Id` is set to 0.

Now `county.AddressId` still has the correct value. So the following works.

```
var address = await Addresses
    .Where(a => a.Id == county.AddressId)
    .FirstOrDefaultAsync();
if (address != null)
    Addresses.Remove(address);
```

My question is why is Address.Id set to 0? For the `.OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.ClientSetNull);` part, I've tried pretty much every `DeleteBehavior` value and they all have the same result.

I've got a working solution. But I'd like to understand why Address.Id is being set to 0 in this case. And from that, figure out if there's a better way to handle this.

Comment: Is there a reason you aren't just using cascade deletes? You appear to be expending a lot of effort to strong-arm EF and a relational database into a pattern that isn't normalized. Often it's better to go with the simplest thing. Split the "Address" table into tables or embedded columns in the respective tables so that the database is happy with the ownership/relationships and can cascade deletes for you.

Comment: @StevePy Yeah I do feel like I'm fighting EF on a couple of things. But I think my underlying schema is best for what I'm doing so fight it is. (And at times I consider reverting back to ADO.NET where I can set this all up so easily.) With that said, thank you for the help you've provided because it has helped me figure out how to accomplish these configurations that are not standard for EF.

Comment: No worries, it's not really an EF issue, but more a Relational one. It looks like you want to define is something like a One-to-One-or-Another in a logical sense, and while EF may support setting up a One-to-One using a FK, behind the scenes in the DB that is a Many-to-One relationship. It might feel odd to have 2 tables with pretty much the same fields, but if you have 100k address records in 1 table, or 20k and 80k records across 2 tables, storage-wise it makes no difference and performance-wise the second option will be faster. It also enables proper 1-to-1 relationships and cascading.